# How to render a uploaded file in django?

Tags: javascript, django, upload

I made a  django app that takes input image from the user and provides the path as to where the file is.I want this image to be rendered on a html page.Any comments/ideas

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. You, actually, don't have to wait for response. You can use the FileReader:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader

The idea is:

1. Handle input[type='file'] changed
2. Create FileReader
3. Display string in base64 format in img[src=]

   ```
   <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif" id="img_input">
   ```

Function definition:

```
function handleFile(e) {
    var self = this;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var file = e.target.files[0];

    reader.onload = function(upload) {
        var currentImageData = upload.target.result;
        var imgElem = document.createElement('img');
        imgElem.setAttribute('src', currentImageData);
        document.body.appendChild(imgElem);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

document.querySelector('#img_input').addEventListener('change', handleFile);
```

That is it.

The other way is to wait for AJAX-response and append image path to img-element, but it is not so good, because it is making user to download file while he already has it on a drive.

Comment: can you elaborate as to what is Filereader.I used FileSystemStorage for saving the image.

Comment: It is on client side, not django side. This code shows the image before it is uploaded. FileReader is a part of WebAPI included in browsers. It provide easy way to get image as base64-string, which can be showed in src-attribute of img-element.